# How I can prove that singularities are outside or within the region?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I can not find a way to justify  rl as the singularities $z = -1 + i$  and $z = 1 + i$  are inside the semicircle.

Can you help me please?

---

Consider $~\int\limits_C\frac{z^3e^{iaz}}{z^4+4}\,\mathrm dx=\int\limits_Cf(z)\,\mathrm dz~$where $C$ is the contour consisting of the semi-circle

$C_R$ of the radius R together with the part of the real axis from $-R$ to $R$

---

To find the poles
$$\begin{align}
\text{Let }z^4+4=0\\
\Rightarrow z&=(-4)^{\frac14}\\
&=\sqrt2(-1)^{\frac14}\\
&=\sqrt 2\big[\cos(2k+1)\pi+i\sin(2k+1)\pi\big]^{\frac14}\\
&=\sqrt 2\left[\cos\frac{(2k+1)}4\pi+i\sin\frac{(2k+1)}4\pi\right];\quad k=0,1,2,3\\
&=\sqrt2\left(\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}i\right)\\
&=(\pm1\pm i)\\
&=1+i,1-i,-1+i,-1-i\\
\end{align}$$
are simple poles and $z=1+i,-1+i$ lies in side

Comment: It might help to make more explicit whether $C$ is in the upper half or lower half plane.  From context it appears to be in the upper half plane.  Notice that $1+i$ and $-1+i$ are the poles in the upper half plane.

Comment: Also you need to know that $R$ is sufficiently large (larger than $\sqrt2$), but this is probably a part of a problem, where you intend to let $R \to \infty$ eventually, and in that case it won't matter.

Comment: @Miguel Someone typed the problem based on the images you have uploaded: [1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U0L5x.png), [2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/C5vRA.png). You should check whether the edited versions is what you wanted. (They [mentioned](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/252912/2) that: *I am not sure if I read the exponent in the integral right*.)